# I want to change my categorical variables into numeric form using get_dummies function by using for loop on categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset which have categorical and numeric features . I want to convert my categorical features into numeric form using for loop which iterate through only categorical variables and convert them into numeric form.

I tried this

```
for i in df_balanced.columns[:-1]:

    if (df_balanced[i].dtype == 'object'):
        df_new = pd.get_dummies(i[:], columns=i[:],  drop_first = True)
```

but it gives me empty dataframe

Comment: Can you add some small data sample, 3 rows, 5 columns with 3 categorical features and expected ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#get DataFrame with categorical (non numeric columns)
df1 = df_balanced.iloc[:, :-1].select_dtypes(object)
#remove categorical and join dummies
df =  df.drop(df1.columns, axis=1).join(pd.get_dummies(df1,  drop_first = True))
```

Comment: it's working but it doesn't delete categorical variables.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh - answer was edited.